# jQuery selector with variable in the selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Quick and silly jQuery selector question.

Why this **does not work**: **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Seefeld/w7hMk/19/)**

```
//config
var ThisTable = $('.ReallyLongSillyTableName');


// Function
$(ThisTable + ' > tbody > tr > td:last-child').each(function() {
    $(this).append('Sales Orders: ');
});
```

But, this **does work**: **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Seefeld/w7hMk/20/)**

```
$('.ReallyLongSillyTableName td:last-child').each(function() {
    $(this).append('Some Text');
});
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: `ThisTable` is a reference to a `table` element in the DOM. You cannot concatenate it with a string. You might want to do something like `ThisTable.find('selector_goes_here') [...]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either this:

```
$('tbody > tr > td:last-child', ThisTable).each(function() {
    $(this).append('Sales Orders: ');
});
```

or this:

```
ThisTable.find('tbody > tr > td:last-child').each(function() {
    $(this).append('Sales Orders: ');
});
```

Comment: this isn't _quite_ the same - it doesn't restrict the `tbody` to being a direct child of `ThisTable`.

Comment: @Alnitak - in which case it does not restrict to be a direct child?

Comment: @NewUser when there are other elements between `.ReallyLongSillyTableName` and any `tbody` descendent, e.g. if there were nested tables, or if the matched class was actually on some other element higher-up in the DOM, and not on a table.

Comment: @Alnitak Sure you over complicate the situation. Of course we can use `$("> tbody > ...", ThisTable)` however it is deprecated.

Comment: @VisioN that's a shame - I don't think there's any other efficient way of specifying that.

Comment: @Alnitak Indeed. IMO, transforming `ThisTable` to string and simply concatenating the other selectors to it makes absolutely no technical sense as the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @VisioN - I personally find `parent > child` very useful. Is there any simple alternative to specify this kind of relation?

Comment: @VisioN without it I think you'd have to write `parentObject.children('tbody').children('tr').children('td:last-child')`

Comment: @NewUser `parent > child` is OK, it's `> child` without a parent that's at issue.

Comment: @NewUser `parent > child` selection is useful but often is not very simple and easy to use. Having `ThisTable` as a jQuery object the only way to use this notation is as Alnitak illustrated: `ThisTable.children("tbody").children("tr") ...`. If there are no cases when *only* such explicit case should be used I'd better use `find` or content selection as described in the answer.

Comment: @Alnitak. It's really so unimportant! `<tbody>` can be only a direct child of `<table>` so... what different does it make? same as `tr > td` you can simply remove the tr, td can be only inside tr.

Comment: @gdoron it does matter if you have nested tables.  `.foo > tbody` would only select the outer table, but `.foo tbody` would select outer _and_ inner.  It's the same with `tr > td`.

Comment: @Alnitak. Though I can't find my crystal ball, I believe this is not the case here...

Answer (score 2):

Try like below,

```
ThisTable.find('tbody > tr > td:last-child').each(function() {
    $(this).append('Sales Orders: ');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('.ReallyLongSillyTableName');` is a jQuery object, so you can't use it as String.

So try

```
var ThisTable = '.ReallyLongSillyTableName';


// Function
$(ThisTable + ' > tbody > tr > td:last-child').each(function() {
    $(this).append('Sales Orders: ');
});

$(ThisTable + ' td:last-child').each(function() {
    $(this).append('Some Text');
});
```

and you can use `ThisTable` as above or `$(ThisTable)` (to make it jquery object) for other purpose.

Comment: This is the only answer (so far) that correctly enforces the `.tableClass > tbody` parent-child relationship.

Comment: @thecodeparadox - where would you use this string as a jQuery object? Taking in count it is a single string. Can you think of any examples where this dual mode could be useful? Or is this just a side effect (beneficial in other cases than this)?  Thanks

Comment: @NewUser for example you can use `$(ThisTable).filter()`, here you can you jQuery object and so on. So use `ThisTable` as string or jquery object

Answer (score 0):

1. `var ThisTable = $('.ReallyLongSillyTableName');` is jQuery object (javascript object)
2. `$(ThisTable + ' > tbody > tr > td:last-child')`
   here in `()` you have javascript object + string, that will not give you full string (NOT string + string!)
3. You need `var ThisTable = '.ReallyLongSillyTableName';`