# Using :not selector with jquery variable

Tags: jquery, css

After looking at [jQuery selector with variable in the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191218/jquery-selector-with-variable-in-the-selector#11191231)
and a few other posts, I'm not finding an answer to my question, which makes me think maybe I'm maybe going about it wrong.

I have a `.car_ul li` element being passed in as 'el',

I'm trying to operate on `$('.car_ul:not(:animated)')` using `$(':not(:animated)',adult)` - wondering how I can do that?

```
slideLeft: function(el) {

                var adult = el.parent.attr('class')
                var itemWidth = el.outerWidth() + 10
                var leftIndent = parseInt(adult.css('left')) + itemWidth


        $('.car_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : leftIndent}, 500,
                        function() {
                            $('.car_ul li:first').before($('.car_ul li:last'))
                            $(adult).css({'left':'-160px'})
                        })

            },
```

Comment: the property is named `className`, FYI. the object version of adult should have worked. Provide html required to recreate your problem and we may be able to help further.

Comment: Or else use `.attr('class')`.

Comment: @Scimonster - don't use jQuery unless needed. `el.parentNode.className` works just fine, and much faster.

Comment: Are you trying to target `.car_ul` elements or descendants of the `.car_ul` elements. Also, it'd probably be a lot easier to understand if you just posted your code instead of trying to talk through it.

Comment: Sorry, posted code so you can actually see what I'm doing. Need to be better about doing that in the first place.

Comment: Ok, figured it out using another variable, but I feel like there's a more efficient way?

ended up using `var adult = el.parent(), adultClass = '.' + adult.attr('class')` and then `$(adultClass + 'li:first')` etc. to select

Comment: have you tried using the documentation-recommended version of `not`? `$(.car_ul').not(':animated').animate({`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for possible optimization points:

```
slideLeft:function($el){
    var $adult = $('.'+$el.get(0).parentNode.className),
        itemWidth = $el.outerWidth() + 10,
        leftIndent = parseInt($adult.css('left'),10),
        $menu = $('.car_ul'),
        $li = $menu.find('li');

    $menu.not(':animated').animate({left:leftIndent},500,function(){
        $li.first().before($li.last());
        $adult.css({left:-160});
    });
},
```

- since you really need the `adult` object, capture that in a variable as an object
- use base 10 for `parseInt` function (**always** do this)
- cache `.car_ul` and its respective `li`
- use the `.not()` method to leverage caching of `.car_ul`
- use the `.first()` and `.last()` methods to leverage caching of `li`
- use the DOM names and numeric values rather than the string values for CSS assignments

I also renamed your `el` variable to `$el` ... this is more stylistic, but its generally considered best practice to call out jQuery objects vs DOM elements with the naming convention.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Definitely! All the pointers are much appreciated, as I'm just getting into using the module pattern, and also not great at JS/jQuery.